# How to merge 150+ Get Request for ScriptResource.axd into 1 without CombineScript

Tags: ajax, get, telerik, request, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxControlToolKit which results in 150+ Get requests for `ScriptResource.axd` even when there are 2 controls on the page. My requirement is to minimize this number of requests. I have tried `CombineScript = "true"` and reduces the number of requests but it is not compatible with the Telerik DLL, hence Telerik gives a JavaScript error and as my application relies heavily on Telerik, I can't choose that option.

Can anyone help me in combining these requests manually without using the `CombineScript` property of AjaxToolKit Script Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has its own ScriptManager called RadScriptManager - you can use that to combine your scripts and it will work fine with the telerik controls.

More details in the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager.html).

Comment: I would hv used RadScriptManager but some ajax controls like ModalPopup don't work with RadScriptManager, these controls need ToolScriptManager to work and as there are multiple ajax controls in my application its not possible to replace all of them with telerik controls. Any other work around.

Comment: You may try the suggested approach here:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/using-ajax-toolkit-modal-dialog-on-same-page-as-telerik-controls#D3XKlKPqu02n6MWxB4AVrA

"To fix it, you should add the MS AJAX's scripts manually (they are available in the AspNetAjaxLibrary - copy them in your application from the zipped distribution and set the path property accordingly) ..."

the link has a sample code too.